# Spring Boot sending empty json for custom FreeMarker login page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I added @Configuration annotated with @EnableWebMvc for custom MVC. It uses Freemarker templates under src/main/resources/templates. Problem is the login page is getting send back to browser as empty json . Do I need to add extra content negotiation or something else? Thx

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver() throws Exception {
    ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
    contentNegotiationManager.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");

    MappingJackson2JsonView defaultView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
    defaultView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    contentViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager.getObject());
    contentViewResolver.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver> asList(viewResolver));
    contentViewResolver.setDefaultViews(Arrays.<View> asList(defaultView));
    return contentViewResolver;
}
  ....
```

}

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class LoginController {

  @RequestMapping("/login")
   public String login() {
      return "login";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The login controller was missing the appropriate content type setting for the client HTTP GET, so I added this produces attribute.
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", produces="application/xml")